# Overloading template class comparison operators

Tags: c++

I am having a ton of trouble with overloading comparison operators in C++. I don't think I am doing it correctly, any help is appreciated. I have provided a snippet of my class below.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    bool operator<  (const A<T>& rhs) const {
        return (value < rhs);
    }
private:
    T value;
};
```

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. If something isn't working you need to explain exactly what isn't and provide a [mcve]

Comment: In `value < rhs` do `value` and `rhs` have the same type?

Answer (score 2):

If you want both `A` objects to be parameterized with the same type `T`, remove the inner `template <typename T>` on the operator.

Otherwise, if you want the operator to take an `A` with a different type parameter than `T`, change the inner `template <typename T>` to `template <typename U>`, and change `rhs` to `const A<U>& rhs`.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can't define nested templates with the same parameter names.

If your `operator<` accepts an `A` object whose template parameter is a different type then the `A` object being compared to, you have to use different template parameter names:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename Other>
    bool operator< (const A<Other>& rhs) const {
        return (value < rhs.value);
    }
private:
    T value;
};
```

This will work as long as `T` and `Other` are types that are comparable with `<`.

However, if you are comparing two `A` objects that have the same template type, there is no need for `operator<` to have its own template at all:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    bool operator< (const A<T>& rhs) const {
        return (value < rhs.value);
    }
private:
    T value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support simple use cases, such as:

```
A<int> a = { some_value };
A<int> b = { some_other_value } ;

if ( a < b ) { ... }
```

there is no need for the `operator<` function to be member function template. You can simplify your code to:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
  public:
    bool operator<(const A& rhs) const {
        return (value < rhs.value);
    }
  private:
    T value;
};
```

If you want to be able to use:

```
A<int> a = { some_value };
A<float> b = { some_other_value } ;

if ( a < b ) { ... }
```

then the `operator<` function needs to be a member function template. However, make sure that the two template parameter names are different. You can use:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
  public:
    template <typename T1>
    bool operator<(const A<T1>& rhs) const {
        return (value < rhs.value);
    }  
  private:
    T value;
};
```

That will work as long as `T` and `T1` support such an operation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want two different template parameters, or one. This is the solution with only one typename (I also added getter for value, just because I prefer to). You don't need inside definition of template and you need to compare the values of the instances, not just value and instance A.

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    bool operator < (const A<T> & rhs) const {
        return (value < rhs.getValue());
    }

   const T & getValue() const{
        return this -> value;
    }
private:
    T value;
};
```

If you want two template arguments there, that is more complicated. Unless you have just few classes that need to work like this, you can do < operator for each. Otherwise it could get messy and I am sure there would be nicer solution for what you want to do.